# error when run scrapy crawl my_scraper -o ehadith.csv

Tags: python, web, scrapy, screen-scraping

I really need help to solve my problem.

I have an error:

```
"[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.islam.gov.my/robots.txt> (referer: None)"
```

When I try running `scrapy crawl my_scraper -o ehadith.csv`

- this is my spiders, ehadith_scrapy.py : https://hastebin.com/ererirawit.py
- this is my output: https://hastebin.com/zinibiqado.coffeescript

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error. That's a debug level log telling you that you're spider successfully downloaded the domain's `robots.txt` file.

The other issue you are having is 403 responses. Try using the [AutoThrottle](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html) extension to reduce requests concurrency.

Comment: thanks, i already try AutoThrottle extension, but still get error " ValueError: invalid hostname:
2018-10-09 04:54:13 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.islam.gov.my/en/e-hadith?start=33> (referer: None) "